# Install doesn't work anymore - Could it be the UEFI?

Tags: boot, 13.10, usb, uefi

It's a long story but I can't keep these details to myself because I have no clue what's going on, it's pretty weird.

I have two hard drives. One had windows, and the other one had nothing, it was brand new. So I installed Ubuntu 13.10 just fine, except for the USB keyboard which would stop working as soon as I pressed ctrl+C trying to copy text (worked just fine on Windows, so it was weird). After a lot of suffering I tried plugging it into different USB ports and somehow it started working fine. Everything was perfect now, but I tried installing the NVIDIA drivers and everything went to hell. I knew it could happen, but I tried anyway because the worst case scenario would be that I would have to reinstall, which wasn't a problem since it was a fresh install anyway and I had time.

The problem is I can't install it correctly anymore! The graphics in the installer are messed up, the screen doesn't refresh until I move the mouse, which leaves horrible trails all over the screen. And it only refreshes the places where I hovered over. I decided I could withstand the installation if at least the fresh install worked fine after that. But no, the fresh install sucks too. The keyboard is slow, the mouse leaves trails, etc.

I thought maybe something was being stored in the boot sector of that disc or whatever. So I deleted the partitions and ran `dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=1 of=/dev/sda` just in case. Didn't fix the problem.

I also downloaded boot-repair and burned a DVD, but after booting and choosing normal/fail-safe and loading for a few seconds it shows a black screen.

My only hope is that this issue is related to BIOS or UEFI (does that even make sense?), which is showing old entries of previous OSs. I have no clue how to edit the UEFI though. The motherboard's DVD didn't help.

Other OS I tried: Fedora 20, black screen.

I also tried connecting only 1 hard drive, tried with both. Didn't work.

Windows 7 still works perfectly, so it's not the VGA. The VGA doesn't store any data, right?

What can I do?

Comment: why not try installing the OS(ubuntu) itself once more.

Comment: @adityapatil I'm saying it doesn't work! The graphics are messed up. That's what makes it so weird. What could have changed that is persistent and affects the installer?

Comment: have you read [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/184942)?

Answer (score 0):

You've either got multiple problems with multiple independent causes (keyboard weirdness, video driver issues, failed installations) or all your problems are related. Occam's Razor says the latter is more likely. Such diverse symptoms can be caused by hardware problems such as bad RAM, a bad CPU, or even a malfunctioning power supply. Thus, I recommend you run some hardware diagnostics, such as memtest86, on your computer. With any luck, one of these tools will identify a problem and you'll be able to fix it.